# What's the time complexity name for O(n*m) (ex: linear, constant)?

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

Big O of n*m isn't listed on wikipedia with a time complexity name, I'm wondering what it is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should probaly be asked here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would give the same answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mathematical expression with one multiplication of two independent variables can be described as [*bilinear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map). Thus `O(n*m)` is describing a bilinear complexity, if it is sure that `n` and `m` are indpependent.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell a simple name like "linear" for this, because it highly depends on the relation between `n` and `m`.

E.g. if n is the number of nodes in a graph and m is the number of edges, then `n*m` can be something link `n³` (cubic), but if the graph is sparse (`m = O(n)`) then `n*m` is in `O(n²)` (quadratic). And it can be anything else if `n` and `m` do not belong to a graph.

So just stay with the formula and add meaning to it by naming `n` and `m` separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that O(nm) is *quadratic*, as nm is a quadratic polynomial in n and m. You can also say that it is linear in both n and m (or bilinear as Sven said).

Answer (score -1):

At most its O(n^2). Typically it will be in between O(n) and O(n^2) since, for every m you do n things or vice versa.

Comment: You are assuming that m=O(n), which is not said.